# Why can't I use my own Brush subclass (in .NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, monomac, brush

I've made a custom System.Drawing.Brush subclass in Xamarin.Mac.  My class looks like this:

```
    // ImageBrush: very much like a System.Drawing.TextureBrush,
    // but based on a Lanet.Drawing.Image instead.
    public class ImageBrush : System.Drawing.Brush {
        public Lanet.Drawing.Image image;

        public ImageBrush(Lanet.Drawing.Image image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public override object Clone() {
            return new ImageBrush(image);
        }
    }
```

This compiles fine, but when I actually pass one of these to a System.Drawing.Pen constructor, the framework throws a System.ArgumentException (A null reference or invalid value was found).

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983677%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) say that "A brush is an instance of any class that derives from the MustInherit (abstract) Brush class".  Seems to me that's what I've got here, but the framework's not buying it.  What am I doing wrong?  Or is this really not possible?

(Note: I'm not concerned about whether this brush actually draws with the standard System.Drawing routines... I just need this as a way to pass my own data around to some custom drawing code.)

Comment: The important part of the `Brush` class is that it wraps a GDI+ brush object. Your derived class doesn't initialize any such brush object.

Comment: Well, sure -- the whole point of my custom drawing code is to work without GDI+ (on Mac and iOS, for example).  I couldn't find any documented requirement that a brush must wrap a GDI+ object.  But, it sounds like this may be the reality anyway.

Comment: It doesn't as part of the public API, of course. This is all private implementation details. But they are absolutely required if you want to use the class along with the rest of the BCL's GDI+ graphics classes. Alternative class libraries have to re-implement the entire System.Drawing namespace.